# ASP.NET MVC Core 3.1 not rendering bootstrap tab properly

Tags: asp.net-core, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-tabs

I have to implement Tab control in the ASP.NET MVC 3.1 which contains bootstrap 4.3.1. Could you please help me? I have just put the HTML markup as below:

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs">
    <li class="active"><a data-toggle="tab" href="#home">Home</a></li>
    <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#menu1">Menu 1</a></li>
</ul>

<div class="tab-content">
    <div id="home" class="tab-pane fade in active">
        <h3>HOME</h3>
        <p>Some content.</p>
    </div>
    <div id="menu1" class="tab-pane fade">
        <h3>Menu 1</h3>
        <p>Some content in menu 1.</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

This is not rendering the tab properly which is something like the screenshot below:
[image]

I want to render the tab as show below:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't people reference back to the [Bootstrap documentation](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.5/components/navs/#base-nav) first to check if they have a valid structure or not?

- Needs `.nav-item` after `.nav`, so in your case, `<li />` needs the class `.nav-item`.
- Anchor tag needs `.nav-link`, which brings in some paddings.
- `.in` is changed to `.show`.

**demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/davidliang2008/sarmvoct/16/

You can style `.tab-content` with paddings to create something that matches up your screenshot:

```css
.tab-content {
    padding: 1rem .25rem;
}
```

**demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/davidliang2008/sarmvoct/20/